# Extract data using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have these text fields.

```
<input type="text" value="<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>" id="tab_4_0_li_div_content"><input type="text" value="lab" id="tab_4_0_li_data"><input type="text" value="<p>dddd</p>" id="tab_4_1_li_div_content"><input type="text" value="client" id="tab_4_1_li_data">
```

Here `tab_4_*_li_data` is a `<li>` html of tab , and `tab_4_0_li_div_content` is `id` of `<div>` which will be show on `<li>` click.

Now I want to extract data from this input fields using regular expression. For example

```
client,lab
```

as key
 and

```
<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>,<p>dddd</p>
```

as value of key.

If you see these are related to each others.

```
tab_4_0_li_div_content        tab_4_0_li_data
<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>             lab

tab_4_1_li_div_content        tab_4_1_li_data
<p>dddd</p>                    client
```

Div content part can content any thing, It's an text area.
So how we do this?

Comment: Here we go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why in the world do you need a regular expression to get the data from attributes?

Comment: @epascarello Because here numbers in key element is dynamic. For example it may be tab_15_50_li_div_content or tab_5_20_li_div_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to have to use a regular expression to parse HTML. One thing, you are not going to have a good time going it. Second, use the power of the DOM

```js
var contents = $("[id$=content]");  //find the elements that have an id that end with content
var datas = $("[id$=data]");   //find the elements that have an id that end with data
var details = {};  //object to hold results
datas.each( function(i) { details[datas[i].value] = contents[i].value; });  //start looping and generate the object with the details you are after
console.log(details);  //Object {lab: "<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>", client: "<p>dddd</p>"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>" id="tab_4_0_li_div_content"><input type="text"   value="lab" id="tab_4_0_li_data"><input type="text" value="<p>dddd</p>" id="tab_4_1_li_div_content"><input type="text" value="client" id="tab_4_1_li_data">
```

Now that code assumes the data and content elements are in the same order, if not, than it would require a little processing, but it is not that hard to do.

```js
    var datas = $("[id$=data]");
    var details = {};
    datas.each(function(i, elem) {
      var id = elem.id;
      var val = $("#" + id.replace("data", "div_content")).val();
      details[elem.value] = val;
    }); 
    console.log(details); //Object {lab: "<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>", client: "<p>dddd</p>"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>" id="tab_4_0_li_div_content">
<input type="text" value="lab" id="tab_4_0_li_data">
<input type="text" value="<p>dddd</p>" id="tab_4_1_li_div_content">
<input type="text" value="client" id="tab_4_1_li_data">
```

Comment: I have these text fields, not as a string. But thanks for the help, i will try to modify it.

Comment: So than it should just be a jquery selector instead of a string. It is the same exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function getValuesById(id1,id2){
    var vals = {};
    if(id1 === undefined)
        id1 = "\\d+";
    if(id2 === undefined)
        id2 = "\\d+";

    $("input").each(function (index, value) {
        console.log(new RegExp('tab_(' + id1 + '_' + id2 + ')_li_data'));
        var match = value.id.match(new RegExp('tab_(' + id1 + '_' + id2 + ')_li_data'));
        if (match) {
            vals[value.value] = $("#tab_" + match[1] + "_li_div_content").val();
        }
    });
    return vals;
}
```

Here I search through all input fields and match against `tab_DIGITS_DIGITS_li_div_data` and put that as a key and corresponding li_div_content as value in object values.

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84c4y2uz/1/)

UPDATE: I have updated the code to a function where you can send in a parameter to your two numerical values and will use any number if not supplied, i.e. use as `getValuesById(4)` for values like `tab_4_*_li`

Comment: Suppose if we have tab_4 as id, Now we want to search those fields which have tab_4_*, So how we can?

Comment: I modify your example. http://jsfiddle.net/84c4y2uz/2/ Please check is this correct.

Comment: @DesipicforuBlogspot I updated mine before seeing you did a change, read update: in my answer :), but your thing should work as well.